# jQuery - Array is Not Showing Correct Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a bootstrap dropdown with checkboxes in it, here is my html:

```
<div class="button-group">
    <button type="button" class="dropdown-search-btn" data-toggle="dropdown">Option 1</button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="Option 1" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" name="makeup"/><span></span>Option 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="Option 2" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" name="makeup"/><span></span>Option 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="Option 3" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" name="makeup"/><span></span>Option 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="Option 4" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" name="makeup"/><span></span>Option 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="Option 5" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" name="makeup"/><span></span>Option 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My problem is that I'm trying to change the dropdown button text with whatever is currently checked in the dropdown list.

Here is my jQuery for getting the values of the checkboxes that are checked and storing them in an array:

```
$(function(){
        $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
            var selection = [];
              $.each($("input[name='makeup']:checked"), function(){            
                    selection.push($(this).val());
                    $(".dropdown-search-btn").text(selection.join(", ")); 
              });
       });
    });
```

This seems to work, it shows the correct values in the console. However, the button text isn't changing properly. For example, if the array has the values of "Option 1, Option 2, Option 3" it will change the button text to "on, on, on" rather than what's in the array. After searching and messing with this for a couple of hours I'm out of ideas, I can't figure out why it's not outputting the correct values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value for a checked checkbox is "on" if the value attribute is missing.

What you want is the text of its parent anchor, which you can get like this:

```
$.each($("input[name='makeup']:checked"), function() {
  selection.push($(this).parent().text());
});
$(".dropdown-search-btn").text(selection.join(", "));
```

**Snippet:**

```js
$(function() {
  $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function() {
    var selection = [];
    $.each($("input[name='makeup']:checked"), function() {
      selection.push($(this).parent().text());
    });
    $(".dropdown-search-btn").text(selection.join(", "));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button-group">
  <button type="button" class="dropdown-search-btn" data-toggle="dropdown"></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="small" data-value="Option 1" tabIndex="-1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="makeup" /><span></span>Option 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="small" data-value="Option 2" tabIndex="-1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="makeup" /><span></span>Option 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="small" data-value="Option 3" tabIndex="-1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="makeup" /><span></span>Option 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="small" data-value="Option 4" tabIndex="-1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="makeup" /><span></span>Option 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="small" data-value="Option 5" tabIndex="-1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="makeup" /><span></span>Option 5</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```